# How to load balance google compute instance using terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

In my terraform configuration file, I define my resource like so:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "test" {
    ...
    count = 2
}
```

What I now want is to create load balancer, that will balance between two instances of my google compute instance. Unfortunatelly, I could not find in documentation anything relative to this task. It seems like `google_compute_target_pool` or `google_compute_lb_ip_ranges` have nothing to do with my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use 'forwarding rules' as indicated on this terraform [document](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_forwarding_rule.html). To use load balancing and protocol forwarding, you must create a forwarding rule that directs traffic to specific target instances. The use on Cloud Platform of forwarding rules you can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/forwarding-rules).

Comment: Thank you, sir! I will check it!

Answer (score 1):

In common cases you can use something like the following:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "test" {
    name         = "nlb-node${count.index}"
    zone         = "europe-west3-b"
    machine_type = "f1-micro"
    count        = 2

    boot_disk {
        auto_delete = true
        initialize_params {
            image       = "ubuntu-os-cloud/ubuntu-1604-lts"
            size        = 10
            type        = "pd-ssd"
        }
    }

    network_interface {
        subnetwork = "default"

        access_config {
            nat_ip = ""
        }
    }

    service_account {
        scopes = ["userinfo-email", "compute-ro", "storage-ro"]
    }
}

resource "google_compute_http_health_check" "nlb-hc" {
    name               = "nlb-health-checks"
    request_path       = "/"
    port               = 80
    check_interval_sec = 10
    timeout_sec        = 3
}

resource "google_compute_target_pool" "nlb-target-pool" {
    name             = "nlb-target-pool"
    session_affinity = "NONE"
    region           = "europe-west3"

    instances = [
        "${google_compute_instance.test.*.self_link}"
    ]

    health_checks = [
        "${google_compute_http_health_check.nlb-hc.name}"
    ]
}

resource "google_compute_forwarding_rule" "network-load-balancer" {
    name                  = "nlb-test"
    region                = "europe-west3"
    target                = "${google_compute_target_pool.nlb-target-pool.self_link}"
    port_range            = "80"
    ip_protocol           = "TCP"
    load_balancing_scheme = "EXTERNAL"
}
```

You can get load balancer external ip via `${google_compute_forwarding_rule.network-load-balancer.ip_address}`

```
// output.tf
output "network_load_balancer_ip" {
    value = "${google_compute_forwarding_rule.network-load-balancer.ip_address}"
}
```